# Web server doesn't run proxy config script in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, http-proxy

I recently deployed my website to server and there is one problem which is I got an error 404 while sending get request for API. I previously got this error when I didn't properly set "ng serve" for proxy config json. However, I fixed all the errors and when I ran it with "npm start" in localhost, I got it

> PS C:\Users\drago\Desktop\lol_search\lolsearch\searchLeague> npm start
>
> search-league@0.0.0 startC:\Users\drago\Desktop\lol_search\lolsearch\searchLeague
>
> ng serve --proxy-config=proxyconfig.json
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

and everything worked perfecly. However, there seems like an error with proxy config again ever since I deployed to server.

This is angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "searchLeague": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/searchLeague",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "searchLeague:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "searchLeague:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "searchLeague:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "searchLeague-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "searchLeague:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "searchLeague:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "searchLeague"
}
```

This is package.json

```
{
  "name": "search-league",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.5.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

This is my proxyconfig.json

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://na1.api.riotgames.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    }
  },
  "/dragon": {
    "target": "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/dragon": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I would be so grate for any solution. Thank you

**UPDATE**

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  })
};


@Injectable()
export class SummonerService {

  private apiurl: string;
  baseApiUrl = environment.baseApiUrl;

  constructor(private  http:  HttpClient) {}

  setURL(name: string){
    this.apiurl = this.baseApiUrl + '/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/' + name + '?api_key=RGAPI-ea0b3ae8-d98b-45c6-adaa-f473fb3d3dc8';
      //this.apiurl = '/api/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/' + name + '?api_key=RGAPI-ea0b3ae8-d98b-45c6-adaa-f473fb3d3dc8';
  }
  setURL2(summonerID: string){
    this.apiurl = this.baseApiUrl + '/lol/league/v4/positions/by-summoner/' + summonerID + '?api_key=RGAPI-ea0b3ae8-d98b-45c6-adaa-f473fb3d3dc8';
    //this.apiurl = '/api/lol/league/v4/positions/by-summoner/' + summonerID + '?api_key=RGAPI-ea0b3ae8-d98b-45c6-adaa-f473fb3d3dc8';
   }

  getdata(name: string): Observable<LOLUserData>{
  this.setURL(name);
  return this.http.get<LOLUserData>(this.apiurl, httpOptions).pipe(
    map(res => res),
    catchError(error => {return throwError(true);}));
  }
```

That is what I did. First of all, I set my base url for api in the environment.prod.ts. In the example links that you sent me, they just set base url for api into a variable such as

> export const environment = { production: true, baseApiUrl: "https://api.com" };

but this caused CORS policy error, so I did the same thing but used /api (one in the proxyconfig.json) to set environment variable like

> export const environment = { production: true, baseApiUrl: "/api" };

it stopped throwing the CORS error but I still see the 404 error and of course in localhost, everything is working perfectly.

I am not sure if get request fails because of invalid configuration for deployment or the API URL being set for get request is just wrong.

Comment: "npm start" or "ng serve" is for dev purpose. If you deploy to server, I think you should consider "ng build" and deploy content in dist to a server, like nginx?
You could consider setting environment to achieve different endpoint: https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

Comment: @Fei I read your link and modified environment.prod.ts just like the link but I had the same error ( API url and 404 error ). should I modify other parts other than environments?

Comment: When you make an API call, consider doing this:
const url = `${environment.endpoint}/your/api/path;
http.get(url, {params: params}) etc. Make your API url depend on your environment. You could probably follow this. It is clearer: https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be

Comment: @Fei I updated the my questions with current status :) please take a look

Comment: I think you are on the right track. It is causing CORS policy error because your API endpoint does not allow CORS. Few ways to resolve:
1. Sending only Simple Request that would not require CORS checking.
2. Config your API server such that it would support CORS. 
https://medium.com/@f2004392/cors-preflight-request-options-9d05b9248e5a
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: To enable CORS support for your server, you would need to handle HTTP OPTIONS Request and response with Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods Access-Control-Allow-Headers configurations.